# Models which can generate contributions

Tags: driverless-ai

I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: Driverless AI Server reported an error: Model does not support pred_contribs=True. Aborting.
```

What generates this error? Which models do not support pred_contribs=True?

Comment: can you post the code you were running from the python client that generated this error? and list the models you have run? The final model can be found in the experiment summary zip.

Answer (score 0):

currently, `pred_contribs` option for the DAI python client should be available, unless your pipeline has TF or rulefit.

Comment: Aha, i think rulefit was the offending model. Thanks